# DC.js Exclude data from one chart, but not others

Tags: charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to exclude a specific value from a chart, but keep it in the dimensions and use it in other charts and totals. I have probably been looking at this too long now and cannot see the answer.

Ex.

```
[{Supplier : "Great supplies", Amount : 200, Count : 20, Date : "2015/7"},
 {Supplier : "Moderate supplies", Amount : 600, Count : 60, Date : "2015/8"},
 {Supplier : "High supplies", Amount : 400, Count : 40, Date : "2015/9"},
 {Supplier : "Other", Amount : 5000, Count : 500, Date : "2015/8"}]
```

I have a line chart that would have the count displayed based on date (y - count, x - month) and it should include all counts, so 20 in July, 560 in August and 40 in September. I have some number displays that give totals; total count : 620, total amount : 6200, unique suppliers : 4.

And I have a ROW chart (y - supplier, x - amount) that will show the top 3 suppliers. For visual purposes, Other is not a top supplier and should not show as the first row with 5000, it should be the other three only.

How do I exclude Other from the ROW chart, without filtering it out of the components? (everything I do seems to result in the Other being dropped out of everything)

Or is it possible to do an offset of `top(3)`, something like `.offset(1).top(3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in the dc.js FAQ: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted You'll want to use a fake group to filter on the key rather than the value of the groups, but otherwise it is almost exactly the same.

Comment: Yep thanks, actually came across that earlier but forgot to post an answer, pretty much found the answer there to use the 'fake' groups.